# Android Listview changing colour of certian positions

Tags: java, android, listview, colors

I have a adapter populating my `Listview` from retrieved json.
I want to change the colour of certain cells dependant on position i.e position 1 blue position 2 red etc. But using the current code i get the desired effect but it gets repeated as i scroll down list. I understand that this is because the view is refreshing but not sure how to fix it.

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

MainActivity main;

ListAdapter(MainActivity main) {
this.main = main;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return  main.countries.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return 0;
}

static class ViewHolderItem {
TextView name;
TextView code;
TextView pts;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
ViewHolderItem holder = new ViewHolderItem();
if (convertView == null) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) main.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, null);

       holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
       holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
       holder.pts = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pts);

       convertView.setTag(holder);
}
else  { 
          holder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
}

holder.name.setText(this.main.countries.get(position).name);
holder.code.setText(this.main.countries.get(position).code);
holder.pts.setText(this.main.countries.get(position).pts);

 if (position == 1) { 
holder.name.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

}

return convertView;

}

}
```

Comment: provide else condition with your desired color for textview background

Comment: Thanks, ive tried that but it still repeats throughout the list.

Comment: you can create a list of colors in size of your list and take the color you want from the colorList by the position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view in the list is recycled. That's the item view scrolled outside to the screed is reused in the item scrolled into the screen. Use code like this.

```
if (position == 1) {
  holder.name.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
} else {
  holder.name.setBackgroundColor(...)   
}
```

Or if you want to divide list by only two item colors:

```
if(position % 2 == 0) view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(224, 224, 235));
if(position % 2 == 1) view.setBackgroundColor(The normal color you should set);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly - you see this colour repeatedly and not only in position 1.
That can happen since you are re-using convertView that's given in getView, and that means that you get an already created and already used View, which has a background colour and had older properties, and you give it new properties and data.
So in that case - it may have the old colour and because you don't give a colour to -each- position, that colour sticks with it.

I think in this case -

```
switch(position){
     case 1:
          holder.name.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
          break;
     case 2:
          holder.name.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EEEEEE"));
          break;
     case 3:
          holder.name.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
          break;
     case 4:
          holder.name.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DDDDDD"));
          break;
     case default:
          holder.name.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ABCDEF"));
          break;
}
```

will solve the recycled colour problem.
(add as many colours as you like to the switch select scope, or create a colour array as was mentioned above and change according to position.